# Error When Enable SSL for Database connection On TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssl, transactionscope

I am trying to Enable SSL for database connection with setting the

**encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true**

on the connection string, everything is working fine until when I want to use TransactionScope, and I am getting below exception,

**The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)**

If I remove encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true part fro mthe connection string then it is fine.

is there someone who experienced this before?

thanks.

Comment: This error typically means you've inadvertently got connections with different connection strings in the same scope, which SQL Server interprets as a request to set up a distributed transaction. Any chance you've got other connections to the same server/database floating around that don't use this connection string? (Matching connection strings is done by matching the *exact* contents; even if two connection strings are logically identical but not textually the same their connections count as going to different databases.)

Comment: You are right, the system was generating the Connection String, and I forgot to put **encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true** tags in one part, I also added this into it now it is working fine. Thanks a lot.